# How to fix loading the datetimepicker in Laravel with adminlte?

Tags: admin, bootstrap-4, laravel-5.5

Please help me to fix this error. I put the script and stylesheet in only this page and write code jquery

```
<script>
     $(function() {
         $( "#datetimepicker" ).datepicker();
       });
</script>
 //html code <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="datetimepicker">
```

But can't load the datetime picker

[image]

Comment: What's the actual error say? all you provided is the line with the error. Also have you tried putting the code in the `<head>`

Comment: I used blade template in laravel framework, but i suspect  I can't run or how to run jquery in this, confusing between **$** or **jquery**

Comment: @YuuOtosaka check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot to add Jquery and css

```js
 $(function() {
         $( "#datetimepicker" ).datepicker();
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="datetimepicker">
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined and **Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined** at factory(jQuery). How to loading jquery in laravel with  blade template

Comment: Add it in head tag. Just copy paste above jquery script above your datepicker js